# Tradução de páginas em arquivos php

Tags: php

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um site que tem apenas 4 páginas, e quero tê-lo em pelo menos seis idiomas, mas o que devo fazer para isso?

Mesmo com poucas paginas, preciso de bastante texto, pois a pagina de login inclui o campo "país", que contém muitos países por exemplo!
A ideia é a seguinte:

pretendo criar varios arquivos em uma pasta "language", como, "***portuguese.inc.php***", "***spanish.inc,php***", "***english.inc.php***"....

E dentro de cada arquivo como exemplo:

```
// Account
$hello          = "Olá";
$welcome        = "Bem-Vindo";
$go_in          = "Entre";
$or             = "ou";
$sign_up        = "Cadastre-se";
$sign_in        = "Entrar";
$forgot_password= "Esqueceu a Senha?";
$logout         = "Sair";
$my_account     = "Minha Conta";

// Languages
$language       = "Idioma";
$english        = "Ingles";
$portuguese     = "Português";
$spanish        = "Espanhol";
$chinese        = "Chinês";
$italian        = "Italiano";
$german         = "Alemão";
$french         = "Francês";
$arabic         = "Arabico";
$russian        = "Russo";
$japanese       = "Japonês";
```

E onde irei usar os arquivos :

***Index.php***

```
<?php
    include_once 'languages/portuguese.inc.php';
    // Minha Conta
    // Olá, Bem-Vindo!
    // Entre ou Cadastre-se!

    echo "$my_account";
    echo "$hello $welcome!";
    echo "$go_in $or $sign_up";
```

O que você acha?

Esta é a melhor alternativa?

Há alguma consequencia nisso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funciona sem problemas da forma como mostrou, mas recomendo que use array e que evite incluir diretamente nas páginas pois pode haver colisão de nomes de variáveis.

**Recomendações**

**1. Nomenclatura dos arquivos de traduções**

Nomeie os arquivos usando códigos ISO. Exemplo, ao invés de portugues.inc.php, utilize pt.inc.php (.inc é desnecessário, mas não é o caso em questão)

**2. Retorno de array da dados**

No arquivo "portugues.inc.php", formate o conteúdo como um array com "return".
Exemplo

```
<?php
return array(
'hello' => 'Olá',
'welcome' => 'Bem vindo',
);
?>
```

Faça o include atribuindo-o a uma variável,

$labels = include_once 'languages/portuguese.inc.php';

Para ler o conteúdo, `echo $labels['hello'];`

**3. Recomendação lógica para tradução de nomes próprios**

Ao traduzir nomes próprios, recomenda-se manter o nome no idioma original.

Observe Um exemplo com a lógica atual:

```
$english        = "Ingles";
$portuguese     = "Português";
$spanish        = "Espanhol";
$chinese        = "Chinês";
```

Suponha um usuário que fale chinês e entra na página por meio de outro idioma, por exemplo, o português. Esse usuário terá enorme dificuldades em navegar pela página ou mesmo conseguir escolher o idioma para chinês porque os labels todos estarão em português. Chineses não fazem a menor ideia do que signifique "chinês" ou mesmo em inglês "chinese". O nmais seguro é manter 2 labels juntos, ou um único no idioma original.

Exemplo

```
$english        = 'English';
$portuguese     = 'Português';
$spanish        = 'Español';
$chinese        = '中文';
```

O mesmo se dá para todos os outros idiomas. Observe que mesmo que não entenda nenhum dos outros idiomas, é visualmente muito mais prático encontrar o idioma desejado.

A segunda forma inclui 2 labels, normalmente o termo no idioma original + idioma internacionalizado/global (inglês)

```
$english        = 'English';
$portuguese     = 'Português (portuguese)';
$spanish        = 'Español (spanish)';
$chinese        = '中文 (chinese)';
```

Essa forma parece desnecessária, pois para quem não entende um idioma, não fará diferença entrar na página com tal idioma.

**4. Array de idiomas**

Os idiomas deveriam ser organizados numa lista particular. Exemplo:

**languages.php**

```
return array(
'en' = 'English',
'pt' = 'Português',
'es' = 'Español',
'cn' = '中文'
);
```

obs: Há "N" formas e técnicas. Portanto, não tenha essa resposta como algo definitivo, como "a melhor solução". Mas com certeza uma solução mais organizada do que o estado atual.

Comment: No caso a tradução apenas ocorrerá em palavras fixas no site? Como traduzir no caso uma descrição de um site de imóveis?

Comment: Sim, o exemplo acima é específico e mais aconselhável para "palavras fixas", ou seja, os labels. Também chamado de conteúdo estático.
Mas também pode se usado para textos dinâmicos. Depende muito da estrutura dos dados do sistema e requisitos.