# Site multilinguagem Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, i18n

Preciso criar um site multilinguagem no codeigniter. Os textos devem vir do banco de dados. Minha inteção é que cada tabela tenha as duas linguagens. Por exemplo. Tabela `sobre` teria

```
id | titulo_br | titulo_en | conteudo_br | conteudo_en
```

e na sessão teria idioma = en. no momento de fazer o select seria mais ou menos assim:

```
$this->db->get('sobre')->result_array();
```

E no html

```
<?php $lang = $this->session->userdata('site')['idioma ];
 echo $dados['titulo_' .$lang] ?>
```

Mas estou achando muito trabalhoso. Tem alguma forma melhor?. Alguma library ou algo do tipo para facilitar?

Comment: Tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto: [Tradução de páginas em arquivos php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76789/91), [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/91) e [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/91).

Comment: Fique atento para formatos ou máscaras de datas, valores monetários e outros caso manipule campos desses tipos. Outra opção é fazer a tradução via javascript alguns plugins: [message.js](https://github.com/messageformat/messageformat.js), [jquery-global](https://github.com/nikgraf/jquery-global), [jquery-localize](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize)

Answer (score -1):

Quando eu fiz um site com duas linguagens em Codeigniter, algum tempo atrás.. utilizei Cookie.

Setei nas bandeiras no topo o seguinte dado dentro de um A:

```
 <a href="<?php print base_url(); ?>idioma/es">ES</a>
```

No routes setei a seguinte rota:

```
$route['idioma/(:any)'] = 'index_home/idioma/$1';
```

Controller do index:

```
  public function index() {

            if (get_cookie('cookie_linguagem')) {

            } else {
                set_cookie('cookie_linguagem', 'pt');
                redirect('/');
            }
    }

public function idioma($id) {

        set_cookie('cookie_linguagem', $id);
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "");
    }
```

No cadastro, obviamente tinha um campo com o nome _pt e o mesmo campo com nome_es (que foram as duas linguagens que utilizei).

Na seleção pelo banco eu verificava o cookie e fazia da seguinte forma:

```
 public function mostra_slides() {
        $idioma = get_cookie('cookie_linguagem');
        $sql = "SELECT imagem_$idioma AS imagem, lead_$idioma AS lead, nome_$idioma AS nome, link FROM tb_slides";
        $q = $this->db->query($sql);
        $row = $q->row();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Ou seja, crio um cookie com o nome pt e seto ele para es quando for necessário.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Gostei da idéia.

Answer (score -1):

Eu não criaria 4 colunas informando de qual idioma seria como no exemplo que você citou:

```
titulo_br | titulo_en | conteudo_br | conteudo_en
```

Eu faria uma tabela normal e só criaria uma coluna para saber em qual idioma aquele registro está

```
id | titulo | conteudo | idioma
```

Um exemplo de registro nessa tabela:

```
1 | Um título | Conteudo da tabela em português | pt
2 | One Title | Content of the table in english | en
```

> Se for um conteúdo específico para ser exibido, crie uma coluna
>   chamada por exemplo **identificacao** e nele coloque uma palavra, ID
>   ou o que achar mais fácil e no `SELECT` faça um `WHERE` puxando esse
>   conteúdo.

Crie os links para selecionar o idioma do site/conteúdo como por exemplo

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('idioma/pt');?>">Português</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('idioma/en');?>">Inglês</a>
```

Em **application/config/routes.php** adicione:

```
$route['idioma/(:any)'] = 'idioma/selecionar_idioma/$1';
```

Controller **idioma**

```
<?php
class Idioma extends CI_Controller{

    public function selecionar_idioma($idioma){

        $this->session->set_userdata('idioma', $idioma);
        redirect('index'); //Página inicial ou outra página
    }
}
?>
```

Quando for exibir o conteúdo da tabela por exemplo:

```
$idioma = $this->session->userdata('idioma');

$this->db->where('idioma', $idioma);
$query = $this->db->get('tabela_do_conteudo');

foreach($query->result() as $result){

    echo $result->titulo.'<br />';
    echo $result->conteudo.'<br /><br />';
}
```

Eu faria mais ou menos assim. Você também pode usar `cookies` se achar melhor que `session`.

Comment: Uma ótima solução também... vou analisar e ver qual a melhor forma. vlw.