# Jogando parâmetro na url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um Projeto em Codeigniter que será em duas linguagens, porém eu preciso permitir esta alteração de linguagem somente na URL do projeto;

Ou seja, ao acessar o dominio.com.br/pt ele deverá manter como base url /pt em todas as páginas e consecutivamente mesma coisa com /en;

Alguém já precisou realizar esta inclusão? Segue abaixo o código do meu .htaccess, config e constants:

Htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1  [R=301,L]

    RewriteBase /cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.110.4/cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/';
```

Constants:

```
define('PATH_FRONT_END', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/');
         define('PATH_FRONT_END_UPLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/web_files/uploads/');
```

Acredito que possa ser realizado algo no routes, porém não faço ideia de como isso possa ser feito.

Comment: Não é melhor trabalhar com sessão?

Comment: Não porque eu utilizei o sistema de idioma igual a seguinte resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155683/site-multilinguagem-codeigniter/155708#155708   e os motores de busca do Facebook não criam sessão ou Cookie e onde tenho os campos com nome_pt, fica nome_ e não pega as informações na hora de compartilhar a publicação em algum link externo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi criada uma constante para jogar o idioma na url:

```
                define('base_path', 'cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/');                
                $uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
                $uri_path = str_replace(base_path, '', $uri_path);
                $uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

                switch ($uri_segments[1]) {
                    case 'pt':
                        define('idioma_site', 'pt');
                    break;
                    case 'es':
                        define('idioma_site', 'es');
                    break;
                    case 'en':
                        define('idioma_site', 'en');
                    break;
                    case 'cms':
                    break;
                    default:
                        header('location: http://192.168.110.4/cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/mauricio/pt');
                        //header('location: http://192.168.110.4/cliente/em_desenvolvimento/back/bernardo/pt');
                        exit();
                    break;
                }
```